# Cannot Work reg Free com Dll(created in VC++) in java

Tags: java, visual-c++, dll, regfreecom

when I use a Reg free COM dll for loading in Java it doesn't work.
But if its registered COM dll it loads...
I don't want to use it in a bare system as registred com dll..

I added manifest for COM component. But when I tried to create an object of CoClass it fails with an error " Failed to create the object" CreateInstance returns "0x80040154". 
Scenario 
1.Loaded c++ dll from java. 
2.c++ dll uses my COM dll.

Please give me solution

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it won't work" bit please?

Comment: I added manifest for COM component. But when I tried to create an object of CoClass it fails with an error " Failed to create the object" 

CreateInstance returns "0x80040154".

Scenario

1.Loaded c++ dll from java.
2.c++ dll uses my COM dll.

Answer (score 0):

Since the manifest file (e.g. MyApp.exe.manifest) works only on processes of the specific executable in the same folder as the manifest (a MyApp.exe in the same folder), I would suggest you try using a wrapper such as  [Lauch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) and use the generated EXE filename as the prefix of your manifest. I'm mostly guessing though.